# Don't insert any combination of duplicates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I just have

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (VAL1, VAL2)
SELECT VAL1, VAL2 FROM OTHER_TABLE;
```

However, if `MY_TABLE` already has the values `(1, 2)`, I don't want to let it insert `(2,1)` if `(2,1)` is in `OTHER_TABLE`;

Is there a way to do this here, or even while creating the tables?

I have tried to `ALTER` the table and create a `UNIQUE` constraint but it doesn't account for duplicates

Comment: You might be able to accomplish it with a trigger. Here are some more ways to look at the issue: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/unique-combination-key-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT VAL1,
       VAL2
FROM   OTHER_TABLE a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   my_table b
                   WHERE  ( a.val1 = b.val2
                            AND a.val2 = b.val1 )
                           OR ( a.val1 = b.val1
                                AND a.val2 = b.val2 ))
```

Comment: beat me to it. Exact same solution i had. There is some performance benefit i believe to using WHERE NOT EXISTS with DML in the new v5.6 engine for those who might complain about the subqueries.

Comment: I believe this works from initial testing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If there is already a UNIQUE constraint on the target table, you should be able to use the IGNORE command to prevent duplicate records.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO MY_TABLE (VAL1, VAL2)
    SELECT VAL1, VAL2 FROM OTHER_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can place a condition while creating the table itself:

create table my_table
(
val1 int,
 val2 int,

check( val,val2 not in (select val1,val2 from other_table,my_table where my_table.val1=other_table.val2 and my_table.val2=other_table.val1)
union
select val1,val2 from my_table mt1,mt2 where mt1.val1=mt2.val2 and mt1.val2=mt2.val1))

);